# OpenAPI spec for reactive REST service using Quarkus

Tags: openapi, quarkus

## The jouney so far

I'm trying to get a reactive REST service up and running, following the [official guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive#using-quarkus-reactive-apis), using RESTEasy and JSON-B.
I also added support for OpenAPI for testing the service following [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui).

Both parts work on their own, the service properly returns the hard coded demo data. The Swagger UI shows the available routes and allows to invoke them.

However, it's not as smooth as I liked it to be...

From the simple, non-reactive routes, schemas have been correctly extracted:

```yaml
Fruit:
  type: object
  properties:
    description:
      type: string
    name:
      type: string
```

But from the reactive routes, empty schemas have been extracted. For example, introducing

```java
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
public Uni<Fruit> getOne(@PathParam(value = "name") String name) {
}
```

resulted in the schema:

```yaml
UniFruit:
  type: object
```

Is there a way to re-use the existing `Fruit` schema?

I tried annotating the route, but that didn't have any effect:

```java
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
// @Schema(ref = "#/components/schemas/Fruit")  // Nope...
// @Schema(ref = "Fruit")                       // Nope...
public Uni<Fruit> getOne(@PathParam(value = "name") String name) {
}
```

Ideally, I wouldn't want to annotate every reactive method separately anyways.

## The question

Is there a way to *configure project-wide* to use the schema of `T` whenever a route returns `Uni<T>` or `Multi<T>`?

Comment: This is something that Quarkus should fix. Thanks for spotting ! https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8811

Answer (score 0):

I have browsed the MicroProfile OpenAPI spec https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-open-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/microprofile-openapi-spec.adoc but could not find a way to do the project wide schema change you request. You can do it for a given class, but here the class is `Uni` and you want different schemas depending on the parameterized type.

So the fix in Quarkus seems like the viable approach unless SmallRye OpenAPI (the implementation) has some specific ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, you can use the `implementation` attribute of the `@Schema` annotation:

```
@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@APIResponse(
            content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                    schema = @Schema(implementation = Fruit.class)))
    public Uni<Fruit> getOne(@PathParam(value = "name") String name) {
}
```